# How to shift left/right a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR value within a WHEN statement?

Tags: vhdl, alu

I'm attempting to create a parametrizable ALU which handles N-Bit signed data. However the methods I know of shifting left/right, either won't work because the values are defined as STD_LOGIC_VECTOR:

```
--Declaration
A, B, X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N downto 0);
--Usage
OUTPUT <= (A sra X) WHEN OPERATION = "0000" ELSE
```

Or because it's within a WHEN statement:

```
OUTPUT <= (A <= X(N) & X(N downto 1)) WHEN OPERATION = "1001" ELSE
--This causes Type of OUTPUT is incompatible with type of <= error
```

To reiterate, I need to  shift left/right A by X bits. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Full code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.DigEng.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity core is
    Generic (
           N : INTEGER);
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A, B, X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N downto 0);
              OPERATION : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); --Allows us up to 16 operations
              FLAGS : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           ALU_OUTPUT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N downto 0));
end core;

architecture Behavioral of core is
    signal TEMP_OUTPUT : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N downto 0);
begin
    TEMP_OUTPUT <= (A) WHEN OPERATION = "0000" ELSE
                --Bit-wise Logic
                 (A AND B) WHEN OPERATION = "0001" ELSE
                 (A OR B) WHEN OPERATION = "0010" ELSE
                 (A XOR B) WHEN OPERATION = "0011" ELSE
                 (NOT A) WHEN OPERATION = "0100" ELSE
                --Arithmetic
                 STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(A) + 1) WHEN OPERATION = "0101" ELSE
                 STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(A) - 1) WHEN OPERATION = "0110" ELSE
                 STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(A) + SIGNED(B)) WHEN OPERATION = "0111" ELSE
                 STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(SIGNED(A) - SIGNED(B)) WHEN OPERATION = "1000" ELSE
                --Shift
                 --(A <= X(N) & X(N downto 1)) WHEN OPERATION = "1001" ELSE
                 "1111";

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go with this. If you want to use `sra`, then you need to use the correct types. The left operand must be a `BIT_VECTOR` and the right must be an integer. It's output is a `BIT_VECTOR`. So you can define your inputs and outputs as `BIT_VECTOR` instead of `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` and then use a cast to get just your `X` into an integer. I *think* the proper casts would be something like this (but you'll have to double check me as I don't have a VHDL compiler on this machine):

```
--Declaration
A, B, X : in  BIT_VECTOR(N downto 0);
--Usage
OUTPUT <= (A sra to_integer(unsigned(to_stdlogicvector(X)) WHEN OPERATION = "1001" ELSE
```

Or, if possible define `A` as a `BIT_VECTOR` and `X` as a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` to leave out the extra cast.

Alternatively, you could continue to use `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` for your inputs and outputs. But you would then need to cast both operands to the appropriate types and then cast the output:

```
--Declaration
A, B, X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(N downto 0);
--Usage
OUTPUT <= to_stdlogicvector(to_bitvector(A) sra to_integer(unsigned(X)) WHEN OPERATION = "1001" ELSE
```

These should all be available in `ieee.numeric_std.ALL` and `IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164`.

---

The difference between `BIT_VECTOR` and `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` is that `BIT_VECTOR` only has two values: `0` and `1`. Whereas `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` has nine: `U`, `X`, `0`, `1`, `Z`, `W`, `L` ,`H` and `-`. Where:

`U` = uninitialized
`X` = unknown - a multisource line is driven '0' and '1' simultaneously (*)
`0` = logic 0
`1` = logic 1
`Z` = high impedance (tri state)
`W` = weak unknown
`L` = weak "0"
`H` = weak "1"
`-`  = don't care

In general it is better to use `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` as it is more flexible and a better model of real world signals.

---

Looking at your code for the concatenation, I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to assign the MSB of `X` concatenated with the MSB down to the LSB + 1 of `X` to `A` and then assign that to `TEMP_OUTPUT`. I *think* it's the double `<=` assignment that is causing the error.

What you want for an arithmetic right shift is to set the right most bits, less shift number of most significant bits of the output to the left most bits less shift number of least significant bits of the input. Then set all of the shift number of most significant bits of the output to the most significant bit of the input.

The first part is a bit tricky but the second part can easily be accomplished with the `others` keyword.

```
--|right most - shift # * MSB of output|   |left most - shift # * LSB of input| |MSBs of output|  
((N - to_integer(unsigned(X))) downto 0 => A(N downto to_integer(unsigned(X))), others => A(N)) WHEN OPERATION = "1001" ELSE
```

The basic problem you are having is one of type conversions. So you will need to think about what signal needs to be of what type and what types of operands the functions you are using require and cast accordingly.